# ion-router-outlet is overlapped by ion-header

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, layout, ionic4

In my Ionic4/Angular app I put the header and footer in their own components because they are the same on every page. When I do this, the `ion-router-outlet` basically ignores the header, and the `ion-content` is partly hidden behind the header. <strike>Of course I could add a padding-top to my content</strike> (Edit: actually, this too does not work, router-outlet always uses the complete screen - why?), but I think something else is wrong, isn't the purpose of the `ion-content` exactly this, to be smart enough to notice how big it needs to be? BTW, it doesn't make a difference if I omit the `fullscreen` in `<ion-content>`.

main app component:

```
<ion-app>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <ion-content fullscreen>
        <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
    </ion-content>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</ion-app>
```

app-header:

```
<ion-header>
    <h1>my header</h1>
</ion-header>
```

app-footer:

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
        <ion-tab-button tab="foo">
            <ion-label>Foo</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
        <ion-tab-button tab="bar">
            <ion-label>Bar</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'foo',
        loadChildren: './foo/foo.module#FooModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'bar',
        loadChildren: './bar/bar.module#BarModule'
    }
]
```

Comment: where is the code for one of the tabs?

Comment: @AaronSaunders does not matter what's in the tabs, can be a simple `<h1>Hello</h1>` - it is still partly overlapped by the ion-header.

Comment: it matters because I don't get the error, and my code works fine... so clearly there is a difference. You are asking for help but being reluctant to provide all of the code - from "How To Ask A Question" - Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: IMO the code I added is exactly "just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem"... Did it really not overlap for you? Because I now found out that there were a couple mistakes in my code. Please see the answer and solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. The `<ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>` is basically ignored, because `<ion-tabs>` also serves as a router-outlet and renders its content on the full viewport, only excluding the space for the tab-bar. This is why the `<app-header>` was overlapped.

> The ion-tabs component does not have any styling and works as a router
>   outlet in order to handle navigation.

source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs

This mean I can simply use

```
<ion-app>
    <ion-tabs>
        <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
            <ion-tab-button tab="foo">
                <ion-label>Foo</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>
            <ion-tab-button tab="bar">
                <ion-label>Bar</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>
        </ion-tab-bar>
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-app>
```

in the main app component and place the `<app-header>` in the individual tabs.

> Header is a parent component that holds the toolbar component. It's
>   important to note that ion-header needs to be the one of the three
>   root elements of a page

source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/header

Answer (score 1):

I didn't like the option of:

> place the `<app-header>` in the individual tab

It prevents me from doing animations in the header since the header is constantly being replaced. So, I added the following class to ion-tabs, and it updated the `router-outlet` appropriately:

```
.with-header {
  height: auto;
  top: 47px;  // height of your app-header component
}
```

And now you simply use:

```
<ion-app>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <ion-tabs class="with-header">
        <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
            <ion-tab-button tab="foo">
                <ion-label>Foo</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>
            <ion-tab-button tab="bar">
                <ion-label>Bar</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>
        </ion-tab-bar>
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-app>
```